# Generate a data series with several constraints

Tags: r

I would like to generate a set of 62 numbers ranging from 1 to 7 (integer only), and their mean has to be 4.65. On top of this, 28 of those numbers need to have a mean of 4.73 and 34 of them need to have a mean of 4.83.

I have been trying to work this out using excel solver, but what i got is a set of same number.  I turn to R and try to impose standard deviation.. but i'm not so sure how to generate that set of numbers with all these contraints..

```
 x <- rnorm(28, m=4.73, sd=1) 

 y <- rnorm(34, m=4.83, sd=1) 

 z <- rnorm(62, m=4.65, sd=1) 

 z[1:20]

 xtrunc <- x[x <=7]
```

Comment: Ranging from 1 to 7... integer or real ? I mean, are `1.5, 2.31` etc allowed ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be better asked on the "puzzles" stack exchange site.

Comment: Question as provided has no real-number solutions, and the sub-problems have no integer solutions. 28*4.73=132.44, which can't make up from integers. 34*4.83=164.22, same. Grand mean of two such subsets would be (28*4.73+34*4.83)/62 = 4.78, not 4.65.

Answer (score 0):

I have created such a vector in `x3`. Translated in R, your question is:

"a set of 62 numbers"

```
> length(x3)
[1] 62
```

"ranging from 1 to 7"

```
> range(x3)
[1] 4.431431 5.296670
```

"their mean has to be 4.65".

```
> mean(x3)
[1] 4.650001
```

"On top of this, 28 of those numbers need to have a mean of 4.73"

```
> mean(x3[1:28])
[1] 4.73
```

"and 34 of them need to have a mean of 4.83."

```
> mean(x3[1:34])
[1] 4.830001
```

`x3` is:

```
> x3 = c(rep(4.73,28),rep(5.29667,6), rep(4.431431,28))
```

Constructed by applying your constraints in the order of increasing vector length and computing the repeated value required to get the mean to the required value.